# Binding SelectedItem of ComboBox in DataGrid with different type

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, combobox, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a DataGrid which contains ComboBox as column.

Let consider DataGrid having ItemsSource as ObservableCollection and ComboBox ItemsSource is List .

I want to set the ComboBox SelectedItem property based on property in DataGrid ItemsSource.

However Product class has property ProductTypeId of type int and not ProductType.

So how can I set ComboBox SelectedItem so that it display value of Product.ProductTypeId as selected. 
And also I want to bind SeletedItems with Mode = TwoWay so that whenever ComboBox SelectedItem changes it will be reflected in DataGrid's ItemsSource.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `DataGridComboBoxColumn` does exactly what you're looking for.  To use it correctly, you need to understand the following properties:

- `SelectedValueBinding` - this is the binding to the property on your object/viewmodel
- `SelectedValuePath`    - this is the value property on the items inside the `ComboBox`.  This will be assigned to the property you set in `SelectedValueBinding` when the user selects an item from the `ComboBox`.
- `DisplayMemberPath`    - this is the description property on the items inside the `ComboBox`

Setting the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` is a little different; note my example below to see how it is done.

These are the same (except for `SelectedValueBinding`) as you have on a standard `ComboBox`.

Here is an example of what your column might look like.

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Product Type" DisplayMemberPath="ProductType" SelectedValuePath="ProductTypeId" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ProductTypeId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding AvailableProductTypes}"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding AvailableProductTypes}"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: How do I work with SelectedItemBinding, then?

Comment: Thanks, it is the only piece of working code on the net!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and nearly gave it up.
But then I realised that the binding must be attributed with
the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`

```
SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTelefonIndex, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

That worked for me.